# Wordpress is_page() always returned with false

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this code to add some stuff to wordpress pages. But this code is not working. **is_page()** is always returned with false value.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Name Of The Plugin
 * Plugin URI: http://URI_Of_Page_Describing_Plugin_and_Updates
 * Description: A brief description of the Plugin.
 * Version: The Plugin's Version Number, e.g.: 1.0
 * Author: Name Of The Plugin Author
 * Author URI: http://URI_Of_The_Plugin_Author
 * License: A "Slug" license name e.g. GPL2
 */
add_action("init", "only_pages");

function only_pages(){
    if(!is_admin()){
        if(is_page()){
            // Do something here...
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: have you tried is_page('pagename') ; ?

Comment: Yes, used. But not working... :(

Comment: is_page() is actually $wp_query->is_page() so if you var_dump  $wp_query you can see what is valorized and what's not at init

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ok.. here is the solution. Instead of using action hook init, use wp action hook.

```
    /*
 * Plugin Name: Page Test
 */

add_action("wp", "only_pages");

function only_pages(){
    if(!is_admin()){
        wp_reset_query();
        if(is_page()){
            echo 'I am single page';
        }
        else{
            echo 'I am not single page';
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine. Hope this helps.

Comment: You just saved me after 3 hours of trying. This behavior should be explained somewhere on the WordPress website.

Comment: And if you need it sooner, `parse_query` is the earliest hook where `is_page()` will work

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess if it's not working you could grab the `$wpdb` object and check the `post_type`

```
function only_pages(){
     global $wpdb;
     if(!is_admin() & $wpdb->post_type == 'page'):
         //Do something here
     endif;
}
```

Comment: $wpdb->post_type returned with null

Answer (score 0):

```
is_page();
// When any single Page is being displayed.

is_page( 42 );
// When Page 42 (ID) is being displayed.

is_page( 'Contact' );
// When the Page with a post_title of "Contact" is being displayed.

is_page( 'about-me' );
// When the Page with a post_name (slug) of "about-me" is being displayed.

is_page( array( 42, 'about-me', 'Contact' ) );
// Returns true when the Pages displayed is either post ID 42, or post_name "about-me", or post_title "Contact".  Note: the array ability was added at Version 2.5.
```

[Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page)

Answer (score -1):

Try an alternative approach. In every page there is a class named "page" in body css. So you can target this class:

```
    $classes = get_body_class();
    if (in_array('page',$classes)) {
        // Do something
    }
```